# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables

Tags: php

Apologize my english pls...I try write select  with bindValue. I get error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.....
Parameters login and passsword are in $_POST but other are as relation between table. What is wrong ?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT u.id as uziv_id, u.login, u.priezvisko, o.skratka, o.id as odbornost_id,  u.rola,u.platny FROM uzivatelia u, odbornost o  WHERE login =: login AND password = :password  and u.odbornost_id =o.odbornost_id and u.platny='ANO'");

$stmt->bindValue(':login', $_POST['login']);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', md5($_POST['password']) );
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `:login` not `: login`

Comment: SELECT u.id as uziv_id, u.login, u.priezvisko, o.skratka, o.id as odbornost_id,  u.rola,u.platny FROM uzivatelia u, odbornost o  WHERE login =:login AND password = :password  and u.odbornost_id =o.odbornost_id and u.platny='ANO'